# UWP align ListViewItem to bottom

Tags: c#, .net, xaml, win-universal-app

Here is simple list view:

```
<ListBox>
    <ListBoxItem Name="Home">
        <RelativePanel>
            <TextBlock Text="&#xE10F;"/>
        </RelativePanel>
    </ListBoxItem>
     <ListBoxItem Name="Map">
        <RelativePanel>
            <TextBlock Text="&#xE10F;"/>
        </RelativePanel>
    </ListBoxItem>
    <ListBoxItem Name="Settings">
        <RelativePanel>
            <TextBlock Text="&#xE10F;"/>
        </RelativePanel>
    </ListBoxItem>
</ListBox>
```

How to aling last child with name `Settings` to bottom of a list view? So that space between `Map` ans `Settings` will be expanded to maximum

Answer (score 3):

Just use a Grid with 4 rows, say Auto, Auto, *, Auto and put Settings to the last one.

Comment: Thx alot! Great idea

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure if it works with a ListBox too, but in a ListView (which is just newer and better version of a ListBox), you can put a ListViewItem to the very bottom of the ListView by placing it in a footer, like this:

```
<ListView>
    <ListViewItem Content="Home" />
    <ListViewItem Content="Map" />
    <ListView.Footer>
        <ListViewItem Content="Settings" />
    </ListView.Footer>
</ListView>
```

EDIT: I have just discovered that clicking on the footer is not handled by the ItemClick event and I unfortunately haven't found any event which would handle that.

Answer (score 0):

this is how I did it.  Set your row height to "*".  Hope this helps.

```
<RelativePanel>
     <ListBox RelativePanel.AlignTopWithPanel="True" VerticalAlignment="Stretch">
          <ListBoxItem Name="Home" >
               <TextBlock Text="Home"/>
          </ListBoxItem>
          <ListBoxItem Name="Map">
               <TextBlock Text="Map"/>
          </ListBoxItem>
     </ListBox>
     <ListBox RelativePanel.AlignBottomWithPanel="True">
          <ListBoxItem Name="Settings">
               <TextBlock Text="Settings"/>
          </ListBoxItem>
     </ListBox>
</RelativePanel>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try This:

```
<ListView Name="MyListView" VerticalAlignment="Stretch" ItemsSource="{Binding MyListItems}">
    <ListView.ItemsPanel>
        <ItemsPanelTemplate>
            <StackPanel VerticalAlignment="Bottom"></StackPanel>
        </ItemsPanelTemplate>
    </ListView.ItemsPanel>
</ListView>
```